# Perl to get a pattern from a file

Tags: perl

I want to fetch values from file `info.log` and compare them to the string in `$upper`.

This what I tried

```
my $upper = "S14";

open(my $file,  "<",  "info.log")  or die "Can't open info.log: $!";

my $string = $upper;

while (<$file>)  {
  if ( ! -e $string) {
    print " print here $string\n";
  }
}
```

My file looks like this

```
ss1
ss2
ss3
ss4
ss5
ss6
ss7
ss8
```

the program outputs all the contents of the file. It should have not printed `ss4` but it does?

Comment: `-e $string` tests whether a file named `$string` exists. You're not comparing with the contents of the info.log.

Comment: Why is this question tagged `bash`?

Comment: What @Barmar said, and why would it not print `ss4` when `$upper` is `S14` (if it *were* comparing strings, which it's not)?  Sloooow down

Comment: What do you mean by saying that the file contains variables? Files just contain text, they don't contain variables unless they're programming language source.

Comment: @barmar: The OP is clearly not fluent with English. Please afford them the decency that you would expect yourself.

Comment: Is your `"S14"` actually supposed to be `"ss4"`?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be:

```
open (FILE, "< info.log") or die "error msg";
while (<FILE>)  
{
    if (/$upper/) {
        MATCH CASE
    }
}
```

Basically you loop through the file and check each line.  Because you are reading the file in you don't need a variable ($_ is implied). on the check case.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you must *always* start *every* Perl program with `use strict` and `use warnings`.

As other people have noted, the `-e` operator says whether a *file of that name exists*. It doesn't check whether one string appears witin another.

There are a few ways to do this. I would use a regular expression, but without knowing what sort of data you're dealing with, and to avoid confusing you, I have written a solution using the [`index` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/) which returns zero or more if the second string appears within the first.

```
use strict;
use warnings

my $file = 'info.log';

my $upper = 'S14';

open my $fh, '<', $file  or die "Can't open '$file': $!";

my $string = $upper;

while (<$fh>)  {
  if (index($_, $string) >= 0) {
    print "This file contains '$string'\n";
    last;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to just search for the matches, use grep its faster. Otherwise iterate through with a foreach.

```
my $upper="S14";
open(my $file,  "<",  "info.log")  or die "Can't open info.log: $!";
my $string = $upper;
my @lines = <$file>;

my @matches grep { $_ =~ /$string/ } @lines; #searching *faster

foreach (@lines) { #iterating
   chomp; #new line stuff
   if($_ =~ /^$string$/is){
      #stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to copy *everything* from a file into a Perl array then please at least check the size of the file first: it may not contain what you think it does.

Comment: 1) The OP shows only lower-case characters.  How does script match those?  Also, how would you prevent a possible `SS14` in the OP's file from matching--assuming case is not an issue?